# Which is the fastest way to get a slice of an array in c?

Tags: c

I would like to do something like this:

```
char in[] = {'a','b','c','d','f','r','t','b','h','j','l','i'};

char out[3];

out = &in;
```

and get only the first 3 characters

but I get an error of incompatible types

Comment: Use a pointer or copy the slice you want; arrays cannot be assigned to.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs This is wrong in so many ways. `printf` receives a `char *`, not `char`, it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @MarkSegal: https://ideone.com/FyMERy Yes, I did one silly mistake with not printing a single char. But please point all the ways where I was wrong.

Comment: Note that `in` is not a string: it does not have an element with zero value.

Comment: @andrejs I assumed you tried printing from offset 2, not just a single char.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`out` is an *array name*, which can't be modified. There's no straight forward way to get a *slice* of the array in C. You can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(out, in, sizeof out);
```

And you need to take that `in` has sufficient elments to copy from.

Answer (score 4):

As your arrays are not designed to contain strings then the corresponding code can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char in[] = {'a','b','c','d','f','r','t','b','h','j','l','i'};
    size_t n = sizeof( in );
    char out[3];

    memcpy( out, in, sizeof( out ) );
    n -= sizeof( out );
    memmove( in, in + sizeof( out ), n );

    printf( "%*.*s\n", n, n, in );
    printf( "%*.*s\n", sizeof( out ), sizeof( out ), out );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
dfrtbhjli
abc
```

Take into account that you have to trace the actual length of array in.

Another example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char in[] = {'a','b','c','d','f','r','t','b','h','j','l','i'};
    size_t n = sizeof( in );
    char out[3];

    printf( "%*.*s\n\n", n, n, in );

    while ( !( n < 3 ) )
    {
        memcpy( out, in, sizeof( out ) );
        n -= sizeof( out );
        memmove( in, in + sizeof( out ), n );

        printf( "%*.*s\n", sizeof( out ), sizeof( out ), out );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
abcdfrtbhjli

abc
dfr
tbh
jli
```

Answer (score 3):

`out` is an array and array name can't be a modifiable lvalue.

Arrays are not assignable in C.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest three ways:

`strncpy(out, in,  sizeof out)`

`memcpy(out, in, sizeof out)`

`sscanf(in, "%3s", out)`

Also, you should make `out` static or global, or allocate it in heap using `malloc`. Just to make sure that anything beyond or out of the first three characters won't be copied to it.

```
// global
char out[3];
int main() {...
```

.

```
// static
static char out[3];
```

.

```
// heap
char *out = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
free(out);
```

It's up to you which to choose.